# Output of sympy.fourier_transform

Tags: fft, sympy

I run `sympy.fourier_transform` using the following code

```
from sympy import fourier_transform, exp,symbols
from sympy.abc import x, k

a=fourier_transform(exp(-x**2), x, k)

s=symbols('s')
Ori=(s)*exp(-(x**2)/(s**2))
FT=fourier_transform(Ori,x,k)

a.subs({k:1}).evalf()
>>>9.16769605680502e-5
FT.subs({s:1,k:1}).evalf()
>>>FourierTransform(exp(-x**2), x, 1)
```

`a.subs({k:1}).evalf()` is a number, as I was expecting.

But I don't understand the result of `FT.subs({s:1,k:1}).evalf()`. It is not a number even though I applied `.evalf()`. I want to get a numeric value.  What is the problem?

Now I'm using sympy version 1.3, python version 3.7.1. This code was running fine with sympy version 1.1.

Comment: It looks like sympy 1.3 only simplifies the `FourierTransform` objects in the initial `fourier_transform` call. So a workaround might be `FT = fourier_transform(Ori.subs({s:1}),x,k)` followed by `FT.subs({k:1}).evalf()`